# Web Essentials 2013 @import less issue

Tags: visual-studio, import, less, web-essentials

I'm using Web Essentials 2013 (VS 2013) for Less compiling. I have a less structure like this

style.less :

```
@import '_mixins.less';
@import '_base.less';
```

When editing _base.less, saving and compiling I get an error

```
NameError: .font-size is undefined
```

`.font-size` is the name of the mixin included in _`mixins.less`. Is this a bug within the WE compiler or am I missing something?

Comment: when your file is called base.less you should use `@import "base.less"` without a leading `_` otherwise show your Less code.

Comment: Its called _base.less

Comment: can you show the content of _mixins.less too?